# How to modify/test Upgrade/Incremental/sql..sql script?

Tags: upgrade, civicrm-buildkit

I am following instructions here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/doc/daily-coding.md#upgrade-tests to add and test a schema update - the upgrade is to add 2 columns to the core event table. A (perhaps stupid) question, do I update the latest version of the versioned (e.g 4.6.*alpha.sql, 4.6.*beta) files in ..Incremental/sql? Since this is not a fix/addition to a particular version but part of brand-new functionality, is that a good assumption?

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting the `4.6` branch, then put the upgrade script in the latest `4.6.X.mysql.tpl`. If you're targeting the `master` branch, then use `4.7.alpha1.mysql.tpl`.

As a rule of thumb, we try to minimize schema changes in stable release branches (e.g. 4.6.x) and instead put them in `master`. But that's not absolute.

The difference between a bugfix and a new feature is a bit academic. When a user installs vX.Y.Z., the upgrader needs to apply all schema changes needed to match vX.Y.Z.